# Is there a Threshold for "Out of Memory" error?

Tags: matlab, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

When I use some code like,

```
 x = randi(100,[1000 1000000]);
```

I get the `Out of Memory` error.

However when I have,

```
x = randi(100,[1000 500000]);
```

I don't get any error but my laptop almost stops working!

and that sometimes costs me a `force shutdown`.

I would really prefer the `Out of Memory` error!

Q1+Q2: Is there a ***threshold*** for that error, which I could **adjust**?

Q3: Or any other suggestions (maybe limit the memory that MATLAB can have access)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

### A1: Yes, the Memory is the Treshold

While the Memory is a limit, your observation of ***"almost stops working"*** is related to the CPU-bound processing associated with a task to calculate value for all 500,000,000 elements and get 'em stored. As you can see in **A3** this attempt takes 4GB RAM storage to handle just the **`x`**.

### A2: Yes. Add more Memory to *adjust* the Treshold

If your problem requires larger objects, get more space to store it, if your CPU-bound observation matters, go get the computation from distributed processing ( be it a Cloud or a Grid ) to off-load your localhost.

### A3: Yes. Check MATLAB memory consumed using `whos`

```
mCloud:1> x = randi( 100, [1000 500000] );
mCloud:2> whos
Variables in the current scope:

   Attr Name        Size                     Bytes  Class
   ==== ====        ====                     =====  =====
        ans         1x70                       757  cell
        x        1000x500000            4000000000  double

Total is 500000070 elements using 4000000757 bytes

mCloud:3>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Lets say that in `4G` my memory gets full, can I adjust to have the error when all the variables in MATLAB are more then `3G`? Because even if I use more memory it is possible to hang in some points.

Comment: Try **`help  whos`** Kamtal